# Optimizing Video Load Times on Mobile(Django)

Tags: html, django, video

I'm currently developing a website for a client, which serves as a platform for uploading and showcasing videos to their customers. The site features seven short videos (each under 1 minute) on the landing page. However, I've encountered a loading speed issue when accessing the site on mobile devices; the videos load quite slowly despite a fast internet connection. This issue doesn't occur on PC. The website is hosted on an Ubuntu VPS and is dockerized.

Does anyone have suggestions on how to optimize the loading speed for mobile devices? Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

I implemented lazy loading for the videos, hoping this would enhance the loading speed on mobile devices.

Despite this implementation, the loading speed on mobile remains considerably slow, which is not the case on desktop.

Comment: You need to find bottleneck first and then fix it. There is no silver bullet for everything. We don't know what is the issue

Comment: I think you should create low-resolution versions of those videos and conditionally lode low-resolution versions on mobile devices.